# Setting up a Two Tiered User System in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm pretty new with Django. I'm building my first app using the framework: a simple blog. I want to implement two different types of users: an ordinary user who can only comment on posts, and an admin user who can both comment on posts and create posts.

my current set up is as follows:

models.py:

```
User = get_user_model()
class Author(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
profile_picture = models.ImageField()
def __str__(self):
return self.user.username
```

right now once logged in a user can do everything. From reading the following documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#groups , https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-user . I think the way to do that would be with with different user groups, but like I said I'm new at this. My question is essentially what is the best / simplest configuration I can use to enable a two user system?

Also on a side note while reading through the docs I saw a section saying that if you're starting a new project it's highly recommended to set up a custom user model. I didn't do this. I only have two users in the system currently: myself as a super user, and a test user. Can I just delete the test user and then create a custom user class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can login to the django admin and after that you can see a groups in that create two groups and in that you can give any one group when user login so using this you can achieve that you can give different permission to different user like this
you can also put in html like this

```
{% if request.user.has_perm.view_data%}
   so anyuser have permission can see this
{% endif% }
```

you can also use inside the view like this

```
if user.has_perm(‘blog.can_publish_blog”):
    do somethin
else:
    do something
```

and if any user directly try to access to the url for that you can use django in built decorator in view like this you can restrict whole view

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import permission_required

@permission_required('polls.add_choice')
def my_view(request):
```